# Get the sum of 'value' in the votes table of all posts related to the user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm trying to get the link karma (like reddit does) of a user and display it on his profile page.

> user: id, name, email, password..
>
> posts: id, user_id, title, link, text...
>
> votes: id, user_id, post_id...

I need to be able to get the sum of "value" field in "votes" table of all the posts submitted by the user

This is what I'm using now and a quick `dd($user)` will retrieve all the post and votes by the user. But using `{{ $post->votes->sum('value') }}` on the view will retrieve the sum of each post separately and not all of them together. How can I do that?

```
public function show($user)
    {
        $user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes')->first();
        return view('user/profile')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

Note that `dd($user)` does retrieve all the posts and their votes of the user.

The View (which displays as many times as there as posts related to the user which is not what should be happening)

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
   Link Karma: {{ $post->votes->sum('value') }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Have you tried haveManyThrough() on $user->votes?

Comment: No, I have not. I haven't encoutered that method yet.

Comment: Check the documentation. It's easy. I think It'll work ;)

Comment: @Mithredate `$user->votes` will get me the votes the user has made, I want the votes everybody made on his (the user) posts.

Comment: Then I think you're missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> users: id, name, email, password..
>
> posts: id, user_id, title, link, text...
>
> votes: id, post_id, value, ...

In `App\User` Model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
public function votes(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Vote','App\Post');
}
```

In `App\Post` Model:

```
public function votes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}
```

Then use: 
`App\User::find($user_id)->post()->find($post_id)->votes()->sum('value')` for sum of votes by user `$user_id` on post `$post_id`.
`App\Post::find($post_id)->votes()->sum('value')` for sum of all votes on post `$post_id`.
`App\User::find($user_id)->votes()->sum('value')` for sum of all votes by user `$user_id`.

You can use `foreach()` to loop through any of the combinations.

Comment: Thanks man. apparently yes, I was missing a parenthesis but with your new snippet I was able to create a new variable $linkKarma and pass it to the view, no need to `foreach`